# Sum of Vlookup Excel with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup

I have two data frames like:

```
df1: 
         domain      male        female
0   bukalapak.com   -0.193041   -0.445085
1   blogspot.com    -0.702501   -0.096032
2   kaskus.co.id    -0.176091   -0.477121
3   grid.id         -0.566853   -0.137339
4   idntimes.com    -0.491565   -0.169046`

df2:
    NAME        DOMAIN1             DOMAIN2
0   DINA  bukalapak.com      myvisualiq.net
1   DILA   blogspot.com        utorrent.com
2   DONI   kaskus.co.id      lotusflare.com
```

I just want to make variable which called `lmp` with value of sum `vlookup`. DOMAIN1 or DOMAIN2 refer to data in male column df1 or in **excel** like:

```
VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$646;2;0)+VLOOKUP(C2;Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$646;2;0)
```

where B2 is `bukalapak.com` while `Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$646` is df1.

And the result will be like this:

```
    NAMA        DOMAIN1             DOMAIN2   lmp
0   DINA        grid.id       bukalapak.com   -0.759894
1   DILA   blogspot.com        idntimes.com   -1.194066
2   DONI   kaskus.co.id             grid.id   -0.742944
```

I want to run this calculation in python. I've read vlookup scripts in python but there is no cases like this. Thank youu

Comment: And are you working on `pandas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.map`:

```
m = df1.set_index('domain')['male']
df2['lmp'] = df2['DOMAIN1'].map(m) + df2['DOMAIN2'].map(m)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   NAME       DOMAIN1        DOMAIN2       lmp
0  DINA       grid.id  bukalapak.com -0.759894
1  DILA  blogspot.com   idntimes.com -1.194066
2  DONI  kaskus.co.id        grid.id -0.742944
```